# Custom deleter. Smart pointer std::unique_ptr();

Tags: c++

Не очень могу понять, что происходит в этом коде. 
Нужно создать свой `deleter`, для умного указателя. В итоге нашел этот код, как ответ на `stackoverflow`, но он не работает для меня.

Есть две функции в области видимости файла:

```
Widget* create()
{
  return new Widget();
}

void destroy(Widget* wid)
{
  cout << "I'm inside of deleter" << endl;
  delete wid;
}
```

И сам класс `Widget`:

```
class Widget
{
public:
std::unique_ptr<Widget, void(*)(Widget*)> ptr_;

Widget() : ptr_(create(), destroy)
{

}

~Widget()
{
    cout << "Widget destructor called! Memory deallocated." << endl;
}
};
```

1) Как теперь этим пользоваться?

2) Что это за конструкция `void(*)(Widget*)`?

3) Как понять такой конструктор `Widget() : ptr_(create(), destroy)`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Странный вопрос. Зачем-то же вы этот код искали? Получается примерно - как обращение к доктору: я тут нашел какие-то таблетки, как их принимать? Доктор может сказать дозировку, но вы уверены в наличии болезни? :)
2. Тип, представляющий собой указатель на функцию, принимающую параметр `Widget*` и возвращающую `void`.
3. Конструктор с пустым телом `{}`, инициализирующий поле `ptr_` путем вызова соответствующего конструктора (в данном случае - конструктора для `std::unique_ptr<Widget, void(*)(Widget*)>`, с передачей ему в качестве аргументов результата вызова `create()` и указателя на функцию `destroy`.

P.S. *Чтобы правильно задать вопрос, нужно знать половину ответа*. (с) Шекли

Comment: 2 и 3 понял. 
А первый, я не могу понять, в каком порядке и что вызывать. 
Ну есть тепер у нас этот `ptr_` в классе, а что с ним делать? 
Нужно обращаться к нему при создании экземпляра или что делать? 
Я запускаю этот код и ничего не происходить просто.

Comment: Делать с ним то, для чего его написали. Откуда я знаю, что это за класс и зачем он нужен? Вот вам встречный вопрос - `struct Data { float a, b, c; char * q; int * i; };` - что мне с этим делать? Ваш вопрос **лишен смысла**.

Comment: К примеру. Я создаю указатель на этот класс `std::make_unique<Widget>("Clock")`, а дальше ничего не происходит. 
Может тогда я не правильно это делаю? Я не понимаю просто, как пользоваться тем, что мы передали ссылку на наш делитер, к примеру.. если `unique_ptr` реализован по принципу `RAII`. тогда мы не должны были бы вручную вызывать `destroy`, но эта функция не вызывается..

Comment: Послушайте, если я вам расскажу в самолете - вот этим рычагом шасси поднимают, вот этим закрылки - вы полетите? Простите за грубость, но пойдите же почитайте что такое [интеллектуальные указатели](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:unofficial) и зачем они нужны!

Comment: ладно я понял) спасибо за ответ